# Google search takes too long when logged in to Google account

Tags: google-search, google-account

Recently I've been experiencing very long loading times when searching in Google. On average around 4-5 seconds, however it has always been under 1 second.

[image]

**This happens only when I'm logged in to my google account, otherwise the results are loaded for the same search in 0.5 second.** Tried with different browsers, same result. I'm using mac, however don't know if the client makes a difference, as it seems like the server response takes too long.
Did anyone experience the same problem, or has an idea, how to solve this pretty annoying issue?

Comment: Does it happen with other accounts? It might be searching through your email or something to produce personalized results and hanging there.

Comment: Just tried with another account, and the speed is ok. So it seems that it just happens with my main and most frequently used account. However still don't know what causes the slow searches, as this happens since a few weeks. Also deleted caches, cookies, etc. didn't help.